# C++ passing member field

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a kind of stupid simple question, I'm learning C++ and have the following class...

```
class Client
{
public:
    Window getWindow() { return window; };

private:
    Window window;
};
```

And what I'm wondering is will `getWindow()` return a reference to my private `window` object or a copy? Should I use a pointer here instead?

What's killing me is that in Java the new keyword makes it very clear when and where objects are created, in cpp it's much less clear, and my experience with C makes matters even worse.

Thanks, -Cody

Comment: Returning by value is fine.

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not** return a pointer. It’s completely inappropriate here.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to return a copy of `Window`, or the reference to your existing `Window` object? You can do both, so it all depends on your intent here. If you return a copy, any modifications to it by the caller would not be propagated back to your member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless and until you explicitly state to return a reference it will return a copy. Please note, returning a pointer would not be a good idea at least in c++

TO return a reference, you have to add `&` to the return type

```
class Client
{
public:
    Window& getWindow() { return window; };

private:
    Window window;
};
```

<strike>Note, if you are concerned by the overhead of returning a value, you may be assured that all latest compilers does to some extent `return value optimization`.
Also, if you are using C++11, you can also take advantage of move semantics.</strike>

Comment: Am I correct to assume that pointers are almost always avoided in C++? It seems like they were needed in C and mostly replaced by references in C++.

Comment: Return value optimisation is done here but it doesn’t do what you think it does: in particular, no NRVO is performed because the copy *must* be made.

Comment: `Am I correct to assume that pointers are almost always avoided in C++`. This is a separate question, but in C++ you have to be judgmental in using pointers. There may be certain cases, where you cannot avoid it.

Comment: @CodySmith Generally, yes. Here’s my take on it (and, I might add, large parts of the C++ crowd agree with this presentation): [Modern C++ Style (PDF)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

By default C and C++ return by value.
It returns a copy of your member. A good compiler might optimize the extra call to copy constructor using N/RVO.

If you need to return your member itself(*this is a bad idea*) then you need to return a reference:

```
 Window& getWindow() 
      ^^^
```

Comment: No, NRVO cannot be applied here since no ownership is transferred – the object *must* be copied.

Comment: Since when is returning a reference a bad idea? Doesn't it depend on what one wants to achieve? Furthermore, I believe the original question was precisely about returning a reference, since Java was mentioned.

Comment: @dragonroot: *Since when is returning a reference a bad idea?* It is not. But it becomes a bad idea when you *return a reference to member*.

Comment: @dragonroot: Maybe you should give it a thought for possible reason of why?

Comment: @dragonroot: If you return a reference to your member, You basically give the user of the function licence to kill you, legally.The caller might alter the state of the member & pretty much make it useless for you.Usually you would not want to expose your object to the caller but provide some setter methods which will give you the control to modify the state of the class member & yet provide the caller opportunity to modify your member state.Please leave a comment on this rather quickly because I intend to delete this answer before it slips my mind.